# Why does using ':' in dataframe.iloc() give me a different size of values?

Tags: pandas, matrix, vector, size

In **Python3** with `pandas`, I have the following `csv` format data set like below

Salary_Data.csv

```
YearsExperience,Salary
1.1,39343.00
1.3,46205.00
1.5,37731.00
```

However, I realized when using the `iloc` method, if I use `:` like below(like the **Case 1**), Although that result is the same, the `Size` is represented differently.

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('data')
# Case 1
dataset.iloc[:, :1].values # Size: (3, 1)
# Case 2
dataset.iloc[:, 0].values # Size: (3,)
```

Why does adding `:` give me a different result? and when should I opt to use that `:`?

Comment: When you pass a scalar to iloc; as in Case 1, pandas returns a series. When you pass a slice; as in Case 2, pandas returns a Dataframe with 1 column

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty well documented in the pandas pages.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html

What you are trying to do in Case 1 is to pass a column slice. You have passed :1 which means you want from first column to col 1 which is effectively the first one. Pandas returns an array which is represented by (3,) in your case.

Try:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
x.shape
```

**Output:**

```
(4,)
```

You can get more information on indexing and slicing here:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-slicing-with-labels